# How does the contains method in a binary search tree return false when no conditions are satisfied?

Tags: scala

I have a method for a class that implements a set for integers using the binary search tree data structure. One of the methods is a `contains` method that returns true if a set contains a given integer

Both implementation of the method below is correct, but I'm trying to understand why doing it this way:

```
def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left.contains(x)
    else if (elem < x) right.contains(x)
    else true
```

is sufficient compared to being exhaustive and doing it this way:

```
def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left.contains(x)
    else if (elem < x) right.contains(x)
    else if (elem == x) true
    else false
```

What is the intuitive reason for the method in the first approach returning false if the integer does not belong in the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be suspicious because it appears that the only way to end recursion is by returning `true`.

However I think you will find that the tree has different classes for node elements and leaf elements. What you have shown is the `contains` method for a node. The `contains` method for a leaf will just returns `false`, ending the recursion.

Alternatively, it may be the `left` and `right` are `Option[Node]`. In this case you will get `false` if the `Option` is `None` because `None.contains(_)` is always `false`.

Comment: Ah...of course. The `contains` method in the Empty class always returns false and given that the recursion terminates in an Empty object tree, we get the desired result. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A binary search tree is always constructed such that left branch has elements that are smaller than the node value - `elem`, and right branch elems are all larger than `elem`.

Following this logic if your `x` is neither smaller, nor larger than `elem` you are left with only possibility: it's equal to the `elem`. Hence, no need to test for equality, and the second implementation's: `else false` will  always be a dead branch.

Think about it this way: if you take two numbers and neither of them is smaller or bigger than the other, then they must be the same number.

Comment: The first paragraph is not relevant, as this is a mathematical law that does not depend on how binary search trees are implemented. You could delete it and the answer would still be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I understand the binary search tree conceptually. I'm curious more about how the first method works in Scala.